# 得られるはずの結果とは違う結果が帰ってきてしまいます。「nan」について教えてください。

Tags: python, python3, numpy

最近学習を始めた者です。三次元グラフを二次元配列で表示させたいのですが、どういうわけか「nan」と出てしまいます。
どなたかわかる方がおられれば教えていただきたいです。

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`f3`関数の戻り値がないことが原因で、値が割り当てられず`nan`になります。
関数の末尾に `return answer` を追加すると値が割り当てられます。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f3(x0, x1):
    r = 2*x0**2+x1**2
    ans = r*np.exp(-r)
    return ans #この行を追加

xn = 9
x0 = np.linspace(-2,2,xn)
x1 = np.linspace(-2,2,xn)
y = np.zeros((len(x0),len(x1)))
for i0 in range(xn):
    for i1 in range(xn):
      y[i1,i0]=f3(x0[i0],x1[i1])

print(x0)
print(np.round(y,1))
```

質問の際は[確認可能なサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)になるようにスクリーンショットではなくソースコードを貼った方が回答が付きやすいと思われます。